# Which circle of Hell is the frozen one in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, planes

This should be a quick question for you. Which circle of Hell is the frozen one in Pathfinder?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

Cocytus is the frozen seventh layer of [Hell in the Pathfinder cosmology](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Hell).